# Should "font tuning" of IEEEtran be disabled when using the microtype package with the IEEEtran class?

Tags: ieeetran, microtype, letterspacing

According to the documentation of the `IEEEtran` class,

> IEEEtran normally alters the default interword spacing to
>   be like that used in IEEE publications. The result is text that
>   requires less hyphenation and generally looks more pleasant,
>   especially for two column text. The nofonttune option will
>   disable the adjustment of these font parameters. This option
>   should be of interest only to those who are using fonts
>   specifically designed or modified for use with two column
>   work.

I believe that the above stated goals are also within the remit of the `microtype` package.

I am loading microtype for my manuscript as follows

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{final, activate={true, nocompatibility}, tracking=true, kerning=true, factor=1100, stretch=10, shrink=10, babel=true}{microtype}
\documentclass{IEEEtran}   % <--- pass 'nofonttune' here as package option?
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Should I explicitly disable the font-tuning with the `nofonttune` class option?

- Does loading microtype enhance the appearance by working in harmony with the IEEEtran package's internal font tuning mechanism (double boost), or
- Does the (potentially suboptimal) font tuning of IEEEtran nullify the good work done by microtype (a conflict)?

I have tried both the settings, and whilst there are some big differences, I am unable to figure out which one looks "better". An  informed suggestion on this shall be much appreciated.

Comment: You're better off leaving IEEEtran as is and focusing on your scientific masterpiece instead. I mean, at the end of the day, they will typeset your work as they want before publication.

Comment: @AboAmmar Fair point, but questions on typographic output using LaTeX is central to this forum.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It has nothing to do with the IEEE or what they allow or disallow. The question is purely technical about the interplay between microtype and purported overlapping feature offered by the IEEEtran class.

Comment: The easy solution is to try it and see.  And if you can't see a difference, why bother?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Because I seek an answer on technical grounds, ie are the resisters/variables/interword glue spacing being manipulated by these packages in a helpful orthogonal way or in a destructive clashing way. This probably means getting the feedback from someone familiar with microtype's underlying mechanisms and those who are willing to read how IEEEtran affects these settings